# Does there exist a group of order $ p^\alpha q^\beta$ that is simple?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I am working on an problem that calls for the existance of simple group of order $p^\alpha q^\beta$ with $\alpha , \beta \geq 1$. I was wondering if such a group existed.

Edit: The problem I was working on was burnsides theroem, with the assumption that simple groups cannot have conjagacy classes of order $p^i$. Sorry for the lack of information. Thank you for the help, I will do better to be more clear next time.

Comment: Well, I suppose you could do worse than a quick perusal of this list:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups

Comment: By Burnside theorem, answer is no.

Comment: Well I am trying to prove burnside theroem. So I can't use it. #mesel

Comment: @user160110 You asked a yes/no question with no reference to Burnside or your intent. Perhaps you should be more specific?

Comment: So why are you asking if you know the answer already? In any case I would advise you to read the proof of Burnside's Theorem in a book.

Comment: The book says to use the fact that every simple group has no conjacy classes of a true power of p to prove burnsides theorem. The book itself offers no proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ be a group of order $p^\alpha q^\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta \ge 1$. Then $G$ is not simple.

*Proof*. Let $P \in {\rm Syl}_p(G)$. Finite nontrivial $p$-groups have nontrivial centre, so there exists $1 \ne g \in Z(P)$. If $g \in Z(G)$ then $\langle g \rangle \unlhd G$, contradicting simplicity. Otherwise the conjugacy class of $g$ in $G$ has size $|G:C_G(g)|$ which is a proper power of $q$ (because $P \le C_G(g)$), so $G$ is not simple by the property you are assuming.

In fact what Burnside actually proved, using character theory, is that a finite simple group cannot have a conjugacy class with nontrivial prime power order.